# File jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to setup `Hadoop` cluster on `Fedora 17`.
When I give `/bin/star-all.sh` command daemons are getting started on masters and slaves nodes. 
But when I view log file for data node on master node I get following EROOR

> ERROR org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hadoop1 cause:java.io.IOException: **File /home/hadoop1/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1**
>
> 2013-03-23 15:37:08,205 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server handler 5 on 9100, call addBlock(/home/hadoop1/mapred/system/jobtracker.info, DFSClient_-838454688, null) from 127.0.0.1:40173: error: java.io.IOException: File /home/hadoop1/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
>   java.io.IOException: File /home/hadoop1/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1558)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:696)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)

I am also trying to run wordcound program. While copying data into HDFS using command

**$bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /home/hadoop1/Documents/wordcount/   /home/hadoop1/hdfs/data**
I get following error

> WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /home/hadoop1/hdfs/data/wordcount/pg20417.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1558)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:696)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)

```
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1070)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
at $Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
at $Proxy1.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3510)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3373)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2600(DFSClient.java:2589)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2829)
```

> 13/03/23 15:41:05 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for block null bad datanode[0] nodes == null
>   13/03/23 15:41:05 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Could not get block locations. Source file "/home/hadoop1/hdfs/data/wordcount/pg20417.txt" - Aborting...
>   copyFromLocal: java.io.IOException: File /home/hadoop1/hdfs/data/wordcount/pg20417.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
>   13/03/23 15:41:05 ERROR hdfs.DFSClient: Exception closing file /home/hadoop1/hdfs/data/wordcount/pg20417.txt : org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /home/hadoop1/hdfs/data/wordcount/pg20417.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1558)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:696)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)

Help in this regard is appreciated..

Comment: Check the logs for your name node - do you have any data nodes connected? If not then check the logs for the data nodes. This question has been asked a number of times and usually the cause is either the data nodes are not running, or the dfs.data.dir is configured on the tmp directory, which is cleared when machine restart

Comment: I checked datanode log.. It reads Retrying connect to server:localhost/127.0.0.1:9100: Already tried 9 times... last line of log file is Server at localhost/127.0.0.1:9100 not available yet. I am new to Hadoop.. What could be the reason of this error..

Comment: I tried modifying some config files.. Now I am getting NORouteToHostException at Datanode machine..Is it the issue of firewall blocking ports?? We have SonicWall firewall installed in college premises...

Comment: Are you trying to run in a pseudo cluster (all on the same machine?) or real cluster with 2+ machines?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this issue...

Step I) There was firewall active on master and slaves node machines.. 
I disabled it by following command "systemctl disable iptables.service"

Step II) I wrongly assigned  "hdfs://localhost:9100" to "fs.default.name" in slave's core-sites.xml configuration file. I changed it to "hdfs://master:9100"

Now my Hadoop Cluster is Up..

Thank You Chris for your kind help...

Answer (score 1):

My reason for this error was not enough space on disk (~200MB was not enough).

Answer (score 0):

I delete jobtracker.info on HDFS, then it works.
Hadoop seems to remake it

Answer (score 0):

One more reason for this error (which I encountered) is a messed up /etc/hosts file causing namenode to listen only on the loopback interface.

This caused datanodes not to connect to namenode and replication level was not reached as a side effect.  See  [namenode rejecting connections bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426865/hadoop-namenode-rejecting-connections-what-am-i-doing-wrong) for more detail.